# Displaying data from MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am struggling with printing the number of documents of a collection from MongoDB to localhost using NodeJS. I hope you guys can spend a few minutes looking at my code and telling me how to solve this problem. And could I display 2 values at the same time? I truly appreciate and thank y'all in advance!

```
// NodeJS code
router.get('/statistics', async function(req, res) {
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    const products = dbo.collection("products");
    const num_products = await products.estimatedDocumentCount();
    const users = dbo.collection("users");
    const num_users = await products.estimatedDocumentCount();
    // Can I display 2 values at the same time like this?
    res.render('statistics', { model: num_products, num_users });
});


// HTML
<div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16" style="border-radius: 15px;">
        <div class="w3-left"><i class="fa fa-comment w3-xxxlarge"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-right">
            <h3>{{num_products}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-clear"></div>
        <h4>Total products</h4>
      </div>
<div class="w3-container w3-orange w3-text-white w3-padding-16" style="border-radius: 15px;">
        <div class="w3-left"><i class="fa fa-users w3-xxxlarge"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-right">
          <h3>{{num_users}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-clear"></div>
        <h4>Total users</h4>
      </div>
```

Comment: _"Can I display 2 values at the same time like this?"_: I believe you can. One thing to note is you need to close the `client` at the end of that _get_ call.

Comment: @prasad_ Could you explain why?

Comment: @HuyQuang What kind of problem/errors are you facing here?

Comment: @Koodies I just cannot display the number of documents of a collection in the database on the localhost.

Comment: @HuyQuang what is your result from a console.log of num_products & num_users. By the way I want to check if it's just a mistake here but not your code, its users not products
   const users = dbo.collection("users");
   const num_users = await users.estimatedDocumentCount();

Comment: @Koodies the result is accurate. The true problem here is that I don't know how to display it.

Comment: You are probably sending the reponse as model, try res.render('statistics', { num_products:  num_products, num_users: num_users }); Please read the handlerbar documentation